# Failing to insert multiple items into single row of List view control

Tags: listview, user-interface, win32gui

I'm trying to create Listview control with two column using bellow code.

```
LV_COLUMN lvc = {0};
lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
lvc.cx = 180;
lvc.pszText = _T("Title");
lvc.cchTextMax = _tcslen(lvc.pszText);
ListView_InsertColumn(hwndList, 0, &lvc);

lvc.pszText = _T("ApplicationName");
lvc.cchTextMax = _tcslen(lvc.pszText);
ListView_InsertColumn(hwndList, 1, &lvc);
```

to insert two colomns. This is successfully inserted.
Then i want to add 2 items in 1st row for Title & ApplicationName colomn respectively.

i'm using structure:

```
typedef struct{
   TCHAR m_title[512];
   TCHAR m_Application[512];
  }APPLICATION_LIST;
```

and then trying to insert multiple items in a same row using:

```
APPLICATION_LIST *pAppList = new APPLICATION_LIST;
    if(pAppList)
    {
        _tcscpy(pAppList->m_title,TEXT("My Mozilla"));
        _tcscpy(pAppList->m_Application,TEXT("FireFox"));

    }

            LVITEM lvi = {0};
            lvi.mask =  LVIF_PARAM | LVIF_TEXT;
        lvi.iItem = ListView_GetItemCount(hwndList);
            lvi.pszText = LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK ;
            ListView_InsertItem(hwndList,&lvi);
```

But i'm not able to insert multiple items into same row using this ! where i gone wrong ? No item will be inserted while doing so !

Please help me to correct this code ? Then how can i insert multiple items into same row for the list view control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying the `LVIF_PARAM` flag, but you are not assigning the `lvi.lParam` field.  You need to add that.  Then, to use `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` correctly, the message procedure of the ListView's parent window needs to handle the [`LVN_GETDISPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774818.aspx) notification.  It will provide a pointer to a `LVITEM` struct that specifies which list item and column it wants you to provide text for.  You can use that item's `lParam` to access your `APPLICATION_LIST` pointer and copy the appropriate string into the item's `pszText` buffer.

For example:

```
LV_COLUMN lvc = {0};
lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
lvc.cx = 180;
lvc.pszText = TEXT("Title");
lvc.cchTextMax = lstrlen(lvc.pszText);
ListView_InsertColumn(hwndList, 0, &lvc);
...
lvc.pszText = TEXT("ApplicationName");
lvc.cchTextMax = lstrlen(lvc.pszText);
ListView_InsertColumn(hwndList, 1, &lvc);
```

.

```
typedef struct
{
   TCHAR m_title[512];
   TCHAR m_Application[512];
} APPLICATION_INFO;

APPLICATION_INFO *pAppInfo = new APPLICATION_INFO;
lstrcpy(pAppInfo->m_title, TEXT("My Mozilla"));
lstrcpy(pAppInfo->m_Application, TEXT("FireFox"));

LVITEM lvi = {0};
lvi.mask =  LVIF_PARAM | LVIF_TEXT;
lvi.iItem = ListView_GetItemCount(hwndList);
lvi.pszText = LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK;
lvi.lParam = reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(pAppInfo);
ListView_InsertItem(hwndList,&lvi);
```

.

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
{
    NMDR *nmhdr = reinterpret_cast<NMHDR*>(msg.lParam);
    if ((nmhdr->hwndFrom == hwndList) && (nmhdr->code == LVN_GETDISPINFO))
    {
        NMLVDISPINFO pdi = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(msg.lParam);

        if (pdi->item.mask & LVIF_TEXT)
        {
            APPLICATION_INFO *pAppInfo = reinterpret_cast<APPLICATION_INFO*>(pdi->item.lParam);

            switch (pdi->item.iSubItem)
            {
                case 0:
                    lstrcpyn(pdi->item.pszText, pAppInfo->m_Title, pdi->item->cchTextMax);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    lstrcpyn(pdi->item.pszText, pAppInfo->m_Application, pdi->item->cchTextMax);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
    break;
}
```